# Django ajax query returning u character in serialized return

Tags: ajax, django, json, django-serializer

I have a Django model

```
class StateCensusHistory(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
  year = models.IntegerField()
  population = models.TextField()
  density = models.TextField()
  pop_change = models.TextField()

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "%d, %s\n" % (self.year, self.population)

  class Meta:
    app_label = "app"
    db_table = "state_census_history"
```

that holds the results of a list several lists dumped to a json string via `json.dumps(list_object)`.  This field is returned upon a query via a Serializers json conversion.  My issue is that JSON.parse() is throwing a `SyntaxError` due to an `unexpected token u`.

How can I work around this, short of modifying the text field itself?

In my views file, I get the queryset and return the serialized data via

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"success" : "true", 
                                "data" : serializers.serialize("json", countyData)}), 
                        mimetype = "application/json")
```

and is parsed via

```
var pop = JSON.parse(data[0].fields.density);
```

An example return string value being parsed is

```
{\"density\": \"{u'Penobscot': 40.75222856500098, u'Sagadahoc': 
 122.27083333333333, u'Lincoln': 67.97977755308392, u'Kennebec': 
 123.12237174095878, u'Waldo': 48.02117802779616, u'Cumberland': 
 288.9285325791363, u'Piscataquis': 3.9373586457405247, u'Hancock': 
 30.698239582715903, u'Washington': 12.368718341168325, u'Aroostook': 
 10.827378163074039, u'York': 183.47612497543722, u'Franklin': 
 16.89330963710371, u'Oxford': 25.171240748402518, u'Somerset': 
 12.425648288323485, u'Knox': 108.48302300109529, u'Androscoggin': 
 208.75502815768303}\"}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're encoding the data twice. It's already json from the call to serialise, no need to call json.dumps as well.

Comment: I'm not serializing the data twice.  The database fields contain the results of a `json.dumps` call made some time ago. The entire model instance is being serialized in response to the query from the browser.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You are indeed serialising twice, for the reason I stated.

Comment: When parsing the initial data, I created multiple dict structure to hold the results of several operations.  Those dict structures were then parsed to a json string and saved as a textfield.  My goal is to return the entire model as a json object